# Jquery Dynamically Loaded Growlers through external JS File

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, linux

I'm trying to push growler notifications dynamically generated in a php file..

Heres my main file.

```
                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                        jQuery("#test").click(
 function () {


 jQuery.getScript("php/live_updates.php");

 });
                        });
```

and heres the `live_updates.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.jGrowl("One");
jQuery.jGrowl("Two");
jQuery.jGrowl("Three");
 }); </script>
```

Looking in my web console its getting the file but not running the growlers..

Anyone got any ideas

Comment: try adding `<?php header("Content-Type: application/javascript"); ?>` to the top of the `live_updates.php`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either.

Comment: remove the script tags... this is including a js source file. surprised you aren't having the console yell at you

Comment: [00:46:21.430] Empty string passed to getElementById().